# XML DTD. Пустые елементы

Tags: xml, xmlparser, dtd

Как правильно обозначать в xml-файле пустой элемент:

*DTD*:

```
<!ELEMENT WARNING EMPTY>
```

*XML:*

```
 <WARNING />
```

или

```
<WARNING></WARNING>
```

?

Оба варианта парсеры принимают, как корректные.

Comment: Вопрос состоит в том, почему парсеры оба варианта принимают? Стандартом xml определено, что первая запись является сокращённым вариантом второй. Оба варианта корректны.

Comment: Да. Вопрос в том какой лучше использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags) XML:

```
EmptyElemTag ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '/>'
```

> Empty-element tags may be used for any element which has no content, whether or not it is declared using the keyword EMPTY. For interoperability, the empty-element tag SHOULD be used, and SHOULD only be used, for elements which are declared EMPTY.
>
> Examples of empty elements:

```
<IMG align="left"
 src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/WWW/w3c_home" />
<br></br>
<br/>
```

Оба варианта записи корректны. При этом, обратите внимание, что в пустом элементе могут присутствовать атрибуты. Однако, в целях совместимости, рекомендуется краткая запись.